# How to make powershell script executable only [No read/write Permission]

Tags: powershell, windows-7

I have a `power shell script` which runs on when the user is `logged on and logged off.`
The script have `confidential information such as admin user id and password`.
So i want this script to be `only executable with no read/write permission.`

Is there any way to achieve this.?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Why embed admin credentials in the script?  You can set it up as an event-triggered scheduled task (based on the logon and logoff events), and register it to run under the admin creds.  The password will be stored with the task registration and not visible to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can just convert it to binary, check out this thread: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/4b53e1f1-2706-4be1-9355-65d259a45834/convert-powershell-script-to-exe-file?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: This won't prevent someone from decompiling the executable to see the confidential information. You can use certificates to encrypt the data (so you can only decrypt it by having the private key) but the data is still read as plain text at one point.